# Agda Installation PLFA Configuration

Tags: agda, agda-mode, agda-stdlib

I am trying to use the *[Programming Language Foundation with Agda](https://plfa.github.io/)* plfa library, however the import does not appear to be working properly.

I have cloned the repository and added the repository path to: `~/.agda/libraries` and plfa to `~/.agda/defaults`.

When I create a `test.agda` file and check a single line

```
module plfa.part1.Naturals where
```

I get an import error:

```
You tried to load /Users/johngfisher/Desktop/agda_test/nats.agda
which defines the module plfa.part1.Naturals. However, according to
the include path this module should be defined in
/Users/johngfisher/agda_env/libraries/plfa/src/plfa/part1/Naturals.lagda.md
```

The file is present in the location the import is coming from so I am unsure of why Agda is unable to find it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module plfa.part1.Naturals where
```

defines a module named `plfa.part1.Naturals`

Did you mean to type

```
module test where

open import plfa.part1.Naturals
```

instead?